# How to do DSA verification using java.security library

Tags: public, ecdsasignature, java.security, secp256r1

I have following 3 information

Following were generated using secp256r1

Public Key X & Y: e6144e916243f15500f645388be9245f13f627bda54be86cace719663f1570a51be96a8151e95787fb95064b5620710ed8386cb58faad11d051808172f32b41c
Random Number : aa7bb0e1576270cb374e63ff7891df7b385862aaf5e986412d91eaa74e63dfd1
Signed R & S : 556e3ac54307d54d6da7f638792f63f6c509777aee6e6c3160908dc40188e4951eee7283d4cc402bd65e40dc54e539af3debaddf03841ca8efaa671cbc4aa5e1

How do i do ECDSA verify on these 3 pieces using java.security?
Really appreciate response.

I have no code in Java, original code was written in C, but due to transition to Java, it needs implementation in java